# Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence that converges...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

**Exercise 8.9** from *Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus* by Kenneth A. Ross:

Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence that converges.

(a) Show that if $s_n \geq a$ for all but finitely many $n$, then $\lim s_n \geq a$.
(b) Show that if $s_n \leq b$ for all but finitely many $n$, then $\lim s_n \leq b$.
(c) Conclude that if all but finitely many $s_n$ belong to $[a, b]$, then $\lim s_n$ belongs to $[a, b]$.

---

Here's what I have so far:

Consider the set $S = \{n \in \mathbb N : s_n < a\}$. By assumption, $S$ is a finite nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$. So it must have a maximum, say $M$. Now assume $s = \lim s_n$ and $s < a$. Then for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $$n > N_0\; \text{implies} \mid s_n - s\mid < \epsilon\text{,}$$ or, in the case where $\epsilon = a - s > 0$,   $$n > N_0\; \text{implies} \mid s_n - s\mid < a - s \text{.}$$ Define $N := \max \{N_0, M\}$. Then $$n > N\; \text{implies}\; s_n \geq a\; \text{and} \mid s_n - s\mid < a - s \text{.}$$ The latter inequality implies, in particular, $s_n < a$ for all $n > N$. But this is contradiction, so our assumption that $s < a$ must be false. Thus $s \geq a$. $\square$

---

I was hoping somebody could help me make sense of this. The book suggested drawing a picture, but I couldn't figure out how. So what would this look like on both the  number line and on the $n$-$s_n$ plane? Also, is there a better way to prove part (a)?

Comment: Have you met subsequences?

Comment: It looks a little messy and long, but correct. After $\;\epsilon= a-s>0\;$ , you already reached $$n>N_0\implies |s_n-s|<\epsilon\iff 2s-a=s-\epsilon<\color{red}{s_n<s+\epsilon=a} $$and this already is a contradiction to the fact that  **at most only a finite number** of elements of the sequence $\;\{s_n\}\;$ are less than $\;a\;$ ...end!

Comment: No, but I probably will later today,  I once finish this and monotone and Cauchy.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I'll have to edit that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is good but it can be shortened. Let $N_1$ be a positive integer such that $s_n \ge a$ for all $n \ge N_1$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. There exists a positive integer $N_2$ such that $s > s_n - \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N_2$. If $n \ge \max\{N_1,N_2\}$, then $s > s_n - \varepsilon \ge a - \varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary $s \ge a$ (otherwise, set $\varepsilon = (a - s)/2$ and note $s < a - \varepsilon$ for this choice of $\varepsilon$.)

Comment: Could you explain everything after the "Let $\epsilon = 0$?"

Comment: The statement after "Let $\varepsilon > 0$" follows follows from the $\lim s_n = s$. For the next statement: If $n \ge \max\{N_1,N_2\}$, then $n \ge N_1$ (which implies $s_n \ge a$) and $n \ge N_2$ (which implies $s \ge s_n - \varepsilon$). Thus $s_n \ge s_n - \varepsilon > a - \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge \max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Now since $s > a - \varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon$ was an arbitrary positive number, then $s \ge a$. For if $s < a$, setting $\varepsilon = (a - s)/2$, we would have $s < a - \varepsilon$, contrary to the inequality $s > a - \varepsilon$.

Comment: Oh, gotcha! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think making sense of it would involve drawing a kind of Cauchy sequence, like this typical one:
[image]
Pretty much what's going on is that, if only finitely many $s_n<a$, then when $n$ is large enough, $s_n\geq a$. This, you may recognize, is the definition of a limit (more or less). In this picture, imagine drawing a horizontal line in the $y-$axis lower than the eventual limit as drawn. At some later $n$, every point in the sequence has to be above the line, which again means the limit is larger than the value.

Comment: Ohhhhh. But this isn't necessarily the case, is it? The oscillatory behavior, that is.

Comment: No, it was just a drawing of a sequence in the $n,x_n$ plane. However, if we're in the real line (or plane, or complex). But this oscillating sequence is what's going on in this proof, albeit more abstractly. This is just an exaggeration